# counting words of a file and storing it in array?

Tags: java

again. im gonna ask again about counting words and how to store it in array. So far, all i got is this.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int count;
 void readFile() {
 System.out.println("Gi navnet til filen: ");
 String filNavn = sc.next();

 try{
     File k = new File(filNavn);
     Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(k);
     count = 0;
     while(sc2.hasNext()) {
     count++;
     sc2.next();
     }
     Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(k);
     String a[] = new String[count];
     for(int i = 0;i<count;i++) {
     a[i] =sc3.next();
     if ( i == count -1 ) {
         System.out.print(a[i] + "\n");
     }else{
         System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
     }
     }
     System.out.println("Number of words: " + count);
 }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
```

my code works. but my question is, is there a more simple way to this? And the other question is how do i count the unique words out of the total words in a given file without using hashmap and arraylist.

Comment: Is HashSet an option?

Comment: You could use the `Arrays.copyOf(Object[], int)` method to add room for another string whenever you encounter one. This is how the `ArrayList` works.

Comment: use Arralylist to store the words and use BuffereReader to read line by line the file using `readline()` function and `split` them into words of array.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a simpler way to go about it:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    File f= new File(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
    String line = null;
    String[] res;
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null ){
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(res, tokens);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Also for counting an unique words, as says @Pshemo, you can use HashSet. HashSet is a collection without repeat eny elements. So size of your HashSet will be count.

Comment: we are not allowed to use hashset,map and arraylist

Comment: You can use "contains" mathod in before insertion.

Comment: help. if i dont know the size of my array. what to do? im trying to revise the code above. and i came up to this one. 

 System.out.println("Gi navnet til filen: ");
 String filNavn = sc.nextLine();
 File k = new File(filNavn);
 try{
 Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(k).useDelimiter("\\s+");
     String[] a = k.length();
     for(int i = 0;i<k.length;i++) {
  a[i] = sc3.next();
  
     }
 }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
 }
    }

Comment: @EdgarMiguelSantosCuevas why do you even need to use scanner on file?

Comment: @EdgarMiguelSantosCuevas also what are you allowed to use if not Hashset, arraylist or map? How about a dictionary (in terms a hashtable)?